# Wordpress theme gives warning: invalid argument

Tags: wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme and after installing it. It says this:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /mnt/web7/c0/97/51996897/htdocs/salashomecooking/wp-content/themes/wootique/functions/admin-functions.php on line 3193
```

This is de function. The foreach starts on line 3193

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wooframework_load_google_fonts' ) ) {
function wooframework_load_google_fonts() {
    global $woo_used_google_fonts;

    $c = 0;
    $fonts = '';
    foreach( $woo_used_google_fonts as $font ) {
        if( $c > 0 ) {
            $fonts .= '|';
        } else {
            ++$c;
        }
        $fonts .= $font;
    }

    woo_shortcode_typography_loadgooglefonts( $fonts , 'woo-used-google-fonts' );
} // End wooframework_load_google_fonts()
}
add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'wooframework_load_google_fonts' );
```

How can this be fixed?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in [Wordpress Forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-in-4?replies=4)

Apparently all you need to do is to go to **dashboard** > **mystile theme** > **update framework** and update the framework.